# Showing that a polynomial over subring is reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that $R_1\subseteq R_2$, and both are integral domains.

Further suppose that $R_2$ is a field, where each element $r\in R_2$ is a zero of a polynomial in $R_1[x]$ with the leading coefficient 1.

I want to show that if $a\in R_1\cap R_2$, then any polynomial in $R_1[x]$ with leading coefficient 1 and root $a^{-1}$ is reducible over $R_1$. How should I approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you write $R_1 \cap R_2$ when $R_1 \subseteq R_2$? Also, you want to assume $a \neq 0$ since otherwise $a^{-1}$ is not well-defined?

Comment: Sure, $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that $R_1$ is actually a field. Hence, $a^{-1} \in R_1$ and $x-a^{-1}$ will be a factor. Notice that this only proves reducibility if the degree is $>1$. Otherwise the claim is also false, since $x-a^{-1} \in R_1[x]$ is irreducible.

Comment: How is it easy to see that $R_1$ is a field? Could you please give me a hint or something?

Comment: Hint: Write down an integral equation for $a^{-1} \in R_2$.

Comment: well, to be honest, I don't know anything about integral equations :( if what you mean are from analytic context.

Comment: I mean the hint I have says it is an easy problem using basic properties of rings

Comment: Write down an equation for $a^{-1}$ as written in the claim (monic polynomial having $a^{-1}$ as a root).